# Рваный массив, количество элементов рандомное

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

Попробовал написать Рваный массив, у двумерном массиве количество элементов будет рандомное. Получилось так:

```
public class DoIKnow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x,y;
        x=2+(int)(3*Math.random());
        String text = "Рваный массив";
        char st = 'a';
        char [] [] array = new char[x][];
        for(int s = 0;s<x; s++) {
            y = 2+ (int) (6*Math.random());
            array [s]= new char[y];
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                text += "\n";
                for(int j =0;j<array.length;j++) {
                    array [i][j] = st;
                    st ++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DoIKnow.main(DoIKnow.java:18)
```

В чём проблема? Что означает эта ошибка?

Comment: вот тут `for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` поди накосячили, вот в этом месте `array.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int s = 0; s < x; s++) {
  y = 2 + (int)(6*Math.random());
  array[s] = new char[y];
}
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    array [i][j] = st;
    st++;
  }
}
```

или

```
for (int s = 0; s < x; s++) {
  y = 2 + (int)(6*Math.random());
  array[s] = new char[y];

  for (int j = 0; j < array[s].length; j++) {
    array [s][j] = st;
    st++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю от все души!

Comment: @StrongMuffin На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Это неверно, поскольку вы берете длину целого массива, а не подмассива:

```
for(int j = 0;j<array.length;j++)
```

думаю, что это исправит проблему:

```
for(int j =0;j<array[i].length;j++)
```

Comment: Не исправит. У автора цикл по всем элементам внешнего массива внутри цикла по всем элементам внешнего массива.